# d3.format "none" type not rounding

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting

The [d3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format) states that the (none) format type works "like `g`, but trims insignificant trailing zeros". The `g` format type uses "either decimal or exponent notation, rounded to significant digits."

Mike Bostock [explained](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1152#issuecomment-271917430) that "The none format type trims trailing zeros, but the precision is interpreted as significant digits rather than the number of digits past the decimal point."

If I use `d3.format('.2')(2.0)`, I get `2` (trailing zeros are dropped).

But when I use `d3.format('.2')(2.001)` the result is `2.001`: No rounding happens. I would have expected the result to be `2.0` (rounding to two significant digits, but keeping the zero), or `2` (rounding to two significant digits, then dropping the zero).

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding the syntax?

Comment: Hey, You got wrong, read the documentation properly [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format)

Comment: You are using `d3.format('.2')(2.001)` but you are mentioning any type, `d3.format('.1f')(2.001)` this is what you are looking for, here `.1f` means fixed position for till 1 precision. To get round values till 1 precision use this `d3.format('0.1fd')` this will `d3.format('0.1fd')(2.981)` then you get 3.0

Comment: @saikiran.vsk: Thanks for your comment. My question is about the `(none)` type (the last entry in the list of available types in the documentation you linked to) which is supposed to round the number and omit trailing zeros. The `.1f` type does not omit trailing zeros.

Comment: `d3.format('0.1fd')` I think this the one you are looking for, Am I right?

Comment: @saikiran.vsk: No, types cannot be mixed. Furthermore, `d` would round to integer, not to a specified precision.

Comment: @Jake I don't know, how you got your results... For me `d3.format('.2')(2.001)` returns `"2"` which is the expected behavior: Round to two significant digits (2.0) and drop the trailing zero.

Comment: @altocumulus: Oh, it seems I'm using an outdated version of `d3` (3.5.17, the one that ships with plot.ly). I just tested it with `d3` 4.9.1, and it works like a charm. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Jake Which is no bug, though! Checking the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format) for v3 one notices the lack of the *none* type ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus: You're absolutely right! Would you mind putting those comments into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Jake As the problem no longer persists I suggest you either delete the question or, preferably, write a self-answer explaining the version mismatch. I think this could really be a great help to people, like yourself, coming from plot.ly stumbling into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because I was using an old version of d3 (3.5.17, which ships with the current version of plot.ly 1.27.1).

In that version of d3, the (none) format type [doesn't exist](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format). It was introduced in 2015.